# C#: Getting the correct keys pressed from KeyEventArgs' KeyData

Tags: c#, enums, enum-flags, keyeventargs

I am trapping a `KeyDown` event and I need to be able to check whether the current keys pressed down are : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>  ?

---

I know I need to use the `e.KeyData` from the `KeyEventArgs`, the `Keys` enum and something with Enum Flags and bits but I'm not sure on how to check for the combination.

Comment: Whoa. How'd you do that? the formatting on the keys, I mean.

Comment: @cheeso, he used <kbd> tags around the words... e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the [Modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.modifiers.aspx) property of the KeyEventArgs class.

Something like:

```
//asumming e is of type KeyEventArgs (such as it is 
// on a KeyDown event handler
// ..
bool ctrlShiftM; //will be true if the combination Ctrl + Shift + M is pressed, false otherwise

ctrlShiftM = ((e.KeyCode == Keys.M) &&               // test for M pressed
              ((e.Modifiers & Keys.Shift) != 0) &&   // test for Shift modifier
              ((e.Modifiers & Keys.Control) != 0));  // test for Ctrl modifier
if (ctrlShiftM == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[Ctrl] + [Shift] + M was pressed");
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. I know I was frustrated with this stuff one day.. ;)

Comment: How to check F10+X ? `bx = ((e.KeyCode == Keys.X) && ((e.Modifiers & Keys.F10) != 0));` does not work :( why ? Could you tell me how to check for F10+X ?

Answer (score 1):

I think its easiest to use this:

`if(e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.G))`

Comment: In some cases it is the best way to identify input keys

Answer (score -2):

You can check using a technique similar to the following:

```
if(Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
```

This in combination with the normal key checks will give you the answer you seek.

Comment: That does not work. The ModifierKeys--without masking--cannot possibly be equal to two different values simultaneously :-)

Comment: I know this is a bit old but, it doesn't work, you've got to mask it first...


if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control && (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift)