# Keystroke combinations in c# winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms, combinations, keystroke

does anyone know how i can setup an event handler so that if the keystrokes Alt + Shift + Ctrl + a letter will do something?

Comment: Check this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865774/c-getting-the-correct-keys-pressed-from-keyeventargs-keydata

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
override void OnKeyDown( object sender, KeyEventArgs e )
{
    bool myKeysPressed = (e.KeyCode == Keys.A) &&
                         ((e.Modifiers & Keys.Alt) == Keys.Alt) &&
                         ((e.Modifiers & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift) &&
                         ((e.Modifiers & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sames as Ed's, but shorter and more readable ;)

```
override void OnKeyDown( object sender, KeyEventArgs e )
{
    bool myKeysPressed = (e.KeyCode == Keys.A) &&
                          e.Alt &&
                          e.Shift &&
                          e.Control;
}
```

Comment: why do you need to override? is it not possible to just add an event handler to the keydown event?

Comment: Yes, you can do the same in an event handler

Comment: Ahhh, didn't even know those properties existed.
@Grant:  You would override the method if this code was inside of your target object's class definition, otherwise use the event.